# Assemble existing RAID 0 with mdadm

Tags: fedora, mdadm

The RAID 0 is built using two drives: `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc`. The RAID type is logical using Intel RAID (BIOS setup).
This computer has two system installed: Windows 7 and CentOS. Each one has its own partition on the RAID for data only.

After CentOS update the boot hangs with the following message:

> ```
> Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: 
> No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
> ```

Windows run boot normally and can access the RAID, so this is not a hardware problem nor a BIOS mess-up.

After days of tuning with `fstab` without success, I chose to install Fedora in place of CentOS. After install:

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

Finally I found a solution reading [archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1565988#p1565988) and run:

```
# IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
[...]
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot -1.
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md/imsm0, slot -1.
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md/imsm0 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md/imsm0 as -1
mdadm: Container /dev/md/imsm0 has been assembled with 2 drives
[...]
```

Is this the correct way for using `mdadm` in my case? If yes, how to configure my system to call `mdadm` during boot with `IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1`? The file `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules` starts with:

> ```
>  # do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update
> ```

Comment: What is in `/etc/mdadm.conf`?

Comment: There is no `/etc/mdadm.conf` in my system

Comment: I don't have a system with two drives handy to test, but does adding `rd.auto` to the boot command line help?

Comment: This need to be added in `/etc/default/grub` for the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` ? Will this change the environment variable `IMSM_NO_PLATFORM` ?